# How to optimize a permutation research on collection in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Alright !

Here is an example of what I'm looking to optimise

```
public struct Node
{
    public int ID;
    private float3 node;
}

public struct Border 
{
    public Node[] nodes;

    public bool IsEquals(Node A, Node B)
    {
        return nodes[0].ID == A.ID && nodes[1].ID == B.ID || nodes[0].ID == B.ID && nodes[1].ID == A.ID;
    }
}

public class Shape
{
    private int borderCount;
    private List<Border> bordersCache = new List<Border>(30000);
    private Dictionary<Node,Node> borderRelationList = new Dictionary<Node,Node> (200000);

    private void Something()
    {
        // Assume that the borderRelationList is full with stuff in it
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Node, Node> keyValuePair in borderRelationList)
        {
            Border reference = GetCachedBorder(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
        }
    }

    private Border GetCachedBorder(Node pointA, Node pointB)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < TriangleEdge.count; index++)
        {
            if (bordersCache[index].IsEquals(pointA,pointB))
            {
                return bordersCache[index];
            }
        }

        return  AddNewBorder(pointA,pointB);
    }

    private Border AddNewBorder(Node pointA, Node pointB)
    {
        Border newBorder = new Border() {nodes = new[] {pointA, pointB}};
        bordersCache.Add(newBorder);
        return newBorder;
    }
}
```

Border representing a combination of 2 Nodes I want to add to the cache ( for memory concern and garbage etc ... ) only thoose who are not already present in the list.

The problem is that the current naive implementation is stressing the CPU way too much and need a way to shorten the research

The collections used are not necessarely what I put here and the architecture is flexible on that so any solutions can be implemented.
Any change of structure is possible too.

TLDR : need a way to check combination existence in a collection FAST & even FASTER.

Comment: It's unclear what the point of this code is - especially what `Something` is supposed to do. Are you asking how specifically to optimize `GetCachedBorder` to find a `Border` that has the same two `Node`s? If so, take a look at [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0#applies-to) instead of `List<T>` and implement a [`GetHashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=net-6.0) in `Border`

Comment: In general if there are always supposed to be exactly two Nodes then don't use an array but rather two fields `public Node A; public Node B;` ...

Comment: GetCachedBorder is the bottleneck yeah that's what i'm trying to optimize, the rest of the code don't matter